# GitLab as mirror for CodeCommit

Tags: gitlab, aws-codecommit

For my use case I need to use CodeCommit repositories. But I would also like to use GitLab GUI and features.

If I install GitLab on my server, is there a way to either connect it to CodeCommit repos directly (I just need to browse commits there) or set it as a mirror for CodeCommit so it would contain copies for all CodeCommit repos?

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible to mirror your GitLab repository to an AWS CodeCommit repository. This Gitlab [doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/mirror/push.html#set-up-a-push-mirror-from-gitlab-to-aws-codecommit) explains it. Basically, it helps you setup a CodeCommit repository to use as a replica, then you can set up a recurring job/codepipeline to act upon code changes.

The pre-requisite is to get an IAM user in the AWS account that holds the CodeCommit repo and will use credentials to pull the Gitlab repo into CodeCommit.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question, which asked about mirroring in the opposite direction: CodeCommit to GitLab.

Comment: The link is broken :(

Comment: Link has been updated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, open new repository, go to settings -> General and you can find mirror function there. It will copy remote repository a few times per day.