# AWS CodePipeline for Serverless : Integrating with Gitlab

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am building an application using Lambda, DynamoDB, Cognito, etc.

I want to setup the CI/CD pipeline using AWS tools - AWS codePipeline.

I am using Gitlab for the code repository.

While setting up the build pipeline using Code Pipeline, I found that there is support for Github repositories, but there is `No` support for `Gitlab`  repositories.

One possible way could, I can use of S3. So when a code is pushed to Gitlab repository, it will be uploaded to S3 bucket.

The codePipeline will trigger the build, execute the test cases and then perform the deployment (Creating lambda functions, API Gateway, DynamoDB tables, etc.)

Is there any better way to integrate CodePipeline with Gitlab?

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47063317/1736679) may help by mirroring the Gitlab repo, if requirements allow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get your code from the 3rd party unsupported Git Repo to S3 from where CodePipeline can take over. This blog [1] provides a way using API Gateway and Lambda to integrate any third party Git Repo with CodePipeline.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/integrating-git-with-aws-codepipeline/

Comment: I tried using this guide  https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/git-to-s3-using-webhooks/ to setup the integration between Gitlab and S3. I got an error -  Failed to authenticate SSH session: Waiting for USERAUTH response: GitError    Is there any document which specifies the changes to be done on Gitlab webhook side?

Comment: Add the SSH public key resource "PublicSSHKey" generated by the Cloudformation Stack in the Gitlab user public key settings. Please remember that the public needs to added to each user's account who need to invoke the pipeline when committing a change in the Git repository. The Outputs tab for the CloudFormation stack contain the two webhook endpoint URLs, the output bucket name, and the public SSH key [1].

[1] https://aws-quickstart.s3.amazonaws.com/quickstart-git2s3/doc/git-to-amazon-s3-using-webhooks.pdf

Comment: URL is showing 404, Any new blog available..?

Answer (score 0):

[Third-party Git repositories as source for AWS CodePipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/event-driven-architecture-for-using-third-party-git-repositories-as-source-for-aws-codepipeline/)

Kindly check out the above link for the third-party Git repositories as source for AWS CodePipeline

Answer (score 0):

As of Aug 14, 2023:

AWS announced that AWS CodePipeline now supports GitLab as a source control repository.

For more information regarding GitLab integration with AWS Codepipeline check the following reference:

1. [Announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/08/aws-codepipeline-supports-gitlab/)
2. [GitLab connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/connections-gitlab.html)